# how to obtain a reference to an interface value

Tags: go

Is it possibile to obtain a reference to an Interface Value without 
reccurring to reflection? If not, why not?

I have attempted:

```
package foo

type Foo struct {
    a, b int
}

func f(x interface{}) {
    var foo *Foo = &x.(Foo)
    foo.a = 2
}

func g(foo Foo) {
    f(foo)
}
```

but it fails with:

```
./test.go:8: cannot take the address of x.(Foo)
```

Comment: You can't. The value in an interface is not addressable. If you need a pointer, put a pointer in the interface.

Comment: As JimB pointed out, it is not addressable. The interface value holds a copy of the original, so there would be no point. See related / possible duplicate question: [Types of Go struct methods that satisfy an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015114/types-of-go-struct-methods-that-satisfy-an-interface/41016448#41016448)

Comment: @icza. You really helped me to understad

Answer (score 1):

To clear your doubts if you go by the meaning Assert

> state a fact or belief confidently and forcefully

in your example `x.(Foo)` is just a type assertion it's not a object so you can not get its address.

so at runtime when the object will be created for example

```
var c interface{} = 5
d := c.(int)
fmt.Println("Hello", c, d)  // Hello 5 5
```

it only assert that

> asserts that c is not nil and that the value stored in c is of type int

So its not any physical entity in memory but at runtime `d` will be allocated memory based on asserted type and than the contents of c will be copied into that location.

So you can do something like

```
var c interface{} = 5
d := &c
fmt.Println("Hello", (*d).(int)) // hello 5
```

Hope i cleared your confusion.