# Pointer to an interface vs interface holding a pointer when unmarshaling JSON

Tags: json, go, pointers, interface, unmarshalling

Consider the following struct and interface definitions.

```
type Foo interface {
    Operate()
}

type Bar struct {
    A int
}

func (b Bar) Operate() {
    //...
}
```

Now, if we attempt to perform the following ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HbqTBRfFLwu)):

```
var x Foo = Bar{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"a\": 5}"), &x)
fmt.Printf("x: %+v\nerr: %s\n", x, err)
```

we get the following output:

```
x: {A:0}
err: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type main.Foo
```

However, by replacing the underlying data with the struct type, it goes without a hitch ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-lbQl6aYeNu)):

```
var x Foo = &Bar{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"a\": 5}"), &x)
fmt.Printf("x: %+v\nerr: %s\n", x, err)
```

Output:

```
x: &{A:5}    
err: %!s(<nil>)
```

However, this is quite confusing to me. In our call to Unmarshall, we're still passing a pointer to x, which to my understanding, should be sufficient enough to allow us to modify the Bar underneath. After all, pointers are simply addresses in memory. If we're passing that address, we should be able to modify it, no? Why does the second example work, but not the first? Why does the struct being a pointer make all the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of the different behavior lies in the fact that if the `json` package has to create a new value, that value must be a concrete type and cannot be a (non-concrete) interface type.

Let's elaborate this.

First let's examine your 2nd, working example. Your variable `x` of type `Foo` wraps a pointer value of type `*Bar`. When you pass `&x` to `json.Unmarshal()`, the `json` package will get a `*Foo` pointer value. Pointer to interface! Should not be used, but there it is. The `json` package will dereference the pointer, and get the wrapped value of type `*Bar`. Since this is a non-`nil` pointer, the `json` package can–and will–go ahead and use it for unmarshaling. All good! The `json` package will modify the *pointed* value.

What happens in your first example?

In your first example your `x` variable of type `Foo` wraps a non-pointer struct value. **Values wrapped in an interface cannot be modified.**

What does this mean? The `json` package will again receive a value of type `*Foo`. Then it goes ahead and dereferences it, and gets a `Bar` value wrapped in an interface. The `Bar` value inside the `Foo` interface cannot be modified. The only way for the `json` package to "deliver" the results would be to create a new value that implements `Foo`, and store this value where the initially passed `*Foo` points to. But values of `Foo` cannot be created, it's a non-concrete interface type. So unmarshal returns with an error.

Some addendum. Your 2nd working example:

```
var x Foo = &Bar{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"a\": 5}"), &x)
fmt.Printf("x: %+v\nerr: %s\n", x, err)
```

This works, because we "prepare" a non-`nil` `*Bar` value to unmarshal into, so the `json` package doesn't have to create a value itself. We already prepared and passed a value for the `Foo` interface type (being a value of concrete type `*Bar`).

If we would store a "typed" `nil` pointed in `x` like this:

```
var x Foo = &Bar{}
x = (*Bar)(nil)
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"a\": 5}"), &x)
fmt.Printf("x: %+v\nerr: %s\n", x, err)
```

We will get back the same error (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OdGTfCTWZ7q)):

```
x: <nil>
err: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type main.Foo
```

The explanation is the same: the `json` package cannot use the `nil` pointer to unmarshal the value into. It would again need to create a value of non-concrete type `Foo`, but that is not possible. Only values of concrete types can be created.

Comment: I can understand why passing a straight `Bar` in would leave us with something unmodifiable. However, why does making the pointer to the struct, rather than the interface, make all the difference? We have its address, so we have still pointed to the same data (the `Bar` itself) in memory, no? If we have its address, why can't we modify it just as we would a `*Bar`?

Comment: @ollien We don't have its address, that's the point. Its address would be of type `*Bar`. But what we have is an address of type `*Foo`. You can dereference the `*Foo` pointer which gives you the wrapped value `Bar`. But this is not a pointer type, so we still don't have the address of this `Bar` value.

Comment: Does the `*Foo` not contain the `Bar`? I think that is the source of my confusion. In my mind, they would be at the same location in memory, but I could very well be off-base.

Comment: @ollien The `*Foo` pointer points to an interface value, which is schemantically a (value; type) pair. This address is not the same as the address of the wrapped value. Having a `*Foo` pointer, you can't obtain an address to the wrapped `Bar` value (which would be of type `*Bar`).

Comment: Why can you not get that address?

Comment: @ollien In short, because the language spec does not allow it. In long, because a copy is stored in interface values, and if it would be allowed to take the copy's address, you could only modify the copy which would be the source of even more confusion. For details, see this answer: [How can a slice contain itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077566/how-can-a-slice-contain-itself/36078970#36078970)

Comment: I guess this all makes sense - it seems like an intentional decision. One last thing though. You say that modifying the copy would be the source of confusion. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @ollien If you could obtain a pointer to the non-pointer wrapped value, you modify it, and you would expect the interface value to hold the new value, but obviously it wouldn't. This "modification" could be indirect, e.g. the wrapped value could have a method with pointer receiver which modifies the (pointed) receiver. You call this method, and everyone would think it modified the value (pointed by the receiver), yet, its effect would be lost as that would only be done on a copy.

Comment: I feel bad to keep drawing this out. I apologize. Why would the interface not hold the new value, if we are modifying the memory it points to? There's something I'm missing here that I can't put my finger on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171914/discussion-between-icza-and-ollien).